# Issue with adding a method to a generic stack?

Tags: c#, generics, stack, extension-methods

Let's say we've got a generic list like this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "abc", "demo", "stackoverflow" };
```

When trying to create a new instance of a stack like this, it won't work.

```
Stack<string> stack = new Stack<string>() { "abc", "demo", "stackoverflow" };
```

The compiler says that the Stack<> doesn't have an add method. So I implemented an add method by using the extensionmethods:

```
public static void Add<T>(this Stack<T> stack, T item)
{
    stack.Push(item);
}
```

However, the compiler still gives the same error. But why? Shouldn't the compiler find the method now? Moreover, doesn't the generic stack implement IEnumerable<> and ICollection<>? Why doesn't the stack contain the Add method by default?

Comment: A short look at the MSDN documentation reveals that `Stack<T>` indeed inherits directyl from `System.Object`. What do you need an `Add()` method for when you already have a `Push()` method?

Comment: @JensH I don't need it, I am just interested in getting to know why this issue behaves the way it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collection initializers do not use extension methods; as such, you cannot use a collection initializer with something that does not have an `Add` method-group, such as `Stack<T>`. You could perhaps subclass it, but ***please don't***:

```
class MyStack<T> : Stack<T> // yeuch
{
    public void Add(T item)
    {
        Push(item);
    }
}
...
// please don't do this... think of the kittens...
Stack<string> stack = new MyStack<string>() { "abc", "demo", "stackoverflow" };
```

Comment: I won't, I was just interested in getting to know "why". ;-)

Comment: @Marc Gravell: What are the reasons not to do this kind of subclassing?

Comment: @RestWing it doesn't add anything except an `Add` method that has a different meaning to normal; `Add`, `Push` and `Enqueue` have different names *for the purpose of* expressing their different semantics.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Got it, it should not be done because it can lead to confusion related to what people are used to think when `Add` method is mentioned (addition to a list instead of addition to any collection).

Answer (score 1):

> However, the compiler still gives the same error. But why?

Because `Stack` still does not implement `Add`. Extension methods are not taken into account when parsing shorthand notation.

> Moreover, doesn't the generic stack implement IEnumerable<>?

It does.

> Why doesn't the stack contain the Add method by default?

Why should it? `IEnumerable` does not contain `Add`.

Comment: But ICollection contains Add, doesn't it?

Comment: @Forlan07, its the [ICollection<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx) which has `Add` method , not `ICollection`

Answer (score 1):

Yes Stack implements IEnumerable<T>, ICollection, and IEnumerable, but none of these interfaces have an Add method. Semantically, adding is not the same as pushing; the former adds items to the end of the collection whereas push adds them to the "beginning", more properly on top of the stack. Creating an Add method for stacks would be too confusing and I would not recommend it.

Comment: it is a bit arbitrary to discuss whether push adds to the beginning or end, since the "beginning" and "end" is an internal implementation detail; the important thing is the order in which push/pop interact.